# Can't connect to mySQL with Navicat

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, navicat

Please, I just migrated from Windows to Mac recently. I installed XAMPP on my mac and also installed PHP and MySQL using Homebrew on my mac. I can easily connect to the MySQL from homebrew using the Navicat if I start it using the command `brew services start mysql`

But, the problem is if I stop the brew service and start my XAMPP, I can't connect to MySQL. I can easily connect with phpMyAdmin web, but with Navicat, it keeps throwing error that it can't connect to the `localhost`.

I tried looking up the `port` the MySQL is running and it is `3306`. But using `host=localhost`, `username=root`, `password=<empty>`, `port=3306` but I still get the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the exact error message

Comment: I get this: `2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61 "Connection refused")`

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but I still think it's useful to come up with solutions anyway. I'm using MAMP and I just had a configuration problem, to allow access to MySQL.

When I checked "Allow network access to MySQL", it was OK for me.

Hope it helps someone.

[image]

Comment: I solved mine by uninstalling MySQL with Brew. I discovered that one running underground prevented my XAMPP MySQL to connect because the port is valid.